# How to add an artist's name to and endpoint with Spotify API?

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, spotify

I'm writing a basic page to search an artist's name, and I am having trouble using the endpoints. I can paste the search into my browser, and it works fine. However, when I run my program it doesn't seem to be pulling the query from the URL. It should be the exact same thing I thought?

```
@{
    var message = "...";
    var name = Request.QueryString["query"];
    if (name != null)
    {
        string search = "https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?q=" + name + "&type=artist";
        var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(search);
        request.Method = "GET";

        string output = String.Empty;
        using (var response = request.GetResponse())
        {
            using (var stream = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                output = stream.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
        message = output;
    }
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Task Two</title>
    </head>
<body>
    <h1>Search for an Artist:</h1>
    <form>
        <input type="text" id="query"/>
        <input type="submit" id="search"/>
    </form>
    <p>@message</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you please include the error response message in your question?

Comment: Please post your error code it will be useful to deal with your problems

Answer (score 0):

Close, but you have to specify the 'name' attribute for the input instead of 'id':

```
<form>
    <input type="text" name="query"  />
    <input type="submit" name="search" />
</form>
```